# Bootstrap-Select z-index Issue with Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented `Bootstrap-Select Dropdown` with accordion. Below is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="accordionGESearch" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
      <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="geoFenceSearchContainer" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Search Criteria</h3>
      <div id="searchContainer" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="display: block;" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2"><label>Dropdown</label></div>
          <div class="col-lg-2"> 
            <select id="ddl" class="selectpicker">  
              <option value="0">Select</option>
              <option value="1">A</option>
              <option value="2">B</option>
              <option value="3">C</option>
              <option value="4">D</option>
              <option value="11">E</option>
              <option value="12">F</option>
              <option value="13">G</option>
              <option value="14">H</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-primary',
    size: 2
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu .open
{ z-index: 9999 !important;}

.dropdown-menu .inner
{ z-index: 9999 !important;}
```

But the `dropdown-menu` is not coming over the accordion, rather it appears below and the container has to be scrolled to view the contents of the dropdown. I have tried putting the `z-index` of the `dropdown-menu` to `9999` but it does not work. I have even searched for any resolution of the problem, but none of the answers worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is a non-working [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/zGageQa6fJ) for the same.

Comment: Its parent containing overflow:auto; so you need to change the property to overflow:visible; that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

give `#searchContainer` `overflow: visible;` in the css and it works for me.